# Python dictionary with frequency

Tags: python

I have a dictionary with a key and an item. Basically, keys keep people name and the values keep salary. What I want is that ordering items according to their frequency with the higher value.

```
d = {'name-1': 100, 'name-2':90, 'name-3': 80, 'name-1': 80}
    print OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda t: t[1]))
```

So, the output should be `('name-1':100)`. Because, the occurrence is two in the dict and the salary is the highest.

I can only sort this dict. Could you please help me to get that result ?

Comment: you can never have the same key appear twice at the same level in a dict

Comment: try `print d` ... currently you would get `name-2:90`

Comment: Do you have a suggestion to use another thing instead the dictionary in order to do that task ?

Comment: Use a dictionary, but with unique keys and use lists for the values.

Comment: Why is 'name-1' in there twice. Do they get two salaries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as others have pointed out you cannot have duplicate keys in a dict... however you could easily use a list

```
#d = (('name-1', 100), ('name-2',90), ('name-3',80), ('name-1',80))
names = "name1,name2,name3,name1".split(",")
salaries = map(int,"100,90,80,80".split(","))
d = zip(names,salaries)
print max(d,key=lambda x:names.count(x[0])*1000+x[1])

#('name-1', 100)
print sorted(d,key=lambda x:names.count(x[0])*1000+x[1],reverse=True)
[('name-1', 100), ('name-1', 80), ('name-2', 90), ('name-3', 80)]
```

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to learn python. I have a question why do you multiply x[0] with 1000 ?

Comment: to make sure frequency has highest precidence

Comment: I have one more question, how can I get the similar list "d" as yours ? I have two strings which are names="name1,name2,name3,name1" and salaries="100,90,80,80", Could you please help me ?

Comment: `names = "name1,name2,name3,name1".split(",")`

Comment: Okay, but how can I join two items(name and salary) as your d list ?

Comment: But it returns like that (('name-1', '100'), ('name-2','90'), ('name-3','80'), ('name-1','80')), how to remove single quote from the keys ?

Comment: you cant from the keys ... from the values you can `salaries = map(int,"100,90,80,80".split(","))` that will force them to be integers

Comment: Could you please help me again ? I am trying to add one more field(id) to my list. I tried this one : names = "name1,name2,name3,name1".split(",")
salaries = map(int,"100,90,80,80".split(","))
ids=1
d = zip(names,salaries)
e=zip(d,(ids))
print sorted(e,key=lambda x:names.count(x[0])*1000+x[1],reverse=True) , I am getting an error :TypeError: zip argument #2 must support iteration..........My output should be ['1',(('name-1', 100), ('name-1', 80), ('name-2', 90), ('name-3', 80))]................I am sorry for disturbing you but i got stuck!

Comment: post a new question ... its too hard to read in the comments ... put your full code

Comment: I think you oculd just do `zip(names,salaries,ids)`

Comment: but, zip does not support 3 arguments

Comment: I am getting this :TypeError: zip argument #1 must support iteration

Comment: Thanks, but it adds all id to each list items, I have only one id for this list. So, I want to group the object based on the id. So, the result should be ['1',(('name-1', 100), ('name-1', 80), ('name-2', 90), ('name-3', 80))].

Answer (score 4):

One approach would be to use a dict, but store the values in lists for each key

```
>>> d = {'name-1': [100, 80], 'name-2':[90], 'name-3': [80]}
```

and then

```
>>> sorted(d, key=lambda x:max(d.get(x)), reverse=True)
['name-1', 'name-2', 'name-3']
```

Comment: Simpler and keeps the original dict concept +1

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating that `d` dict?

```
>>> d = {'name-1': 100, 'name-2':90, 'name-3': 80, 'name-1': 80}
>>> d
{'name-1': 80, 'name-2': 90, 'name-3': 80} # notice 'name-1' is only in there once.
>>>
```

If you try to create a second key with the same name in the dict, it will over write the value that was associated with that key.  Every key is unique in a dict... If they weren't unique, dictionaries would no longer be near as useful.

You could create a nested tuples/lists if you need this sort of data structure... However, it will be far slower as finding a key will require iterating over all objects in the list:

```
d = (
        ('name-1', 100),
        ('name-2', 90),
        ('name-3', 80),
        ('name-1', 80),
     )
```